# Why do we need three equations to find the pH of NaCN, given Ka(HCN)?

Tags: acid-base, ph

To find the pH of a 1.0 M solution of $\ce{NaCN}$, given 
$\ce{Ka(HCN) =4.9E(-10)}$

The solution (refer end of question) uses three equations:

Equation 1 : $\ce{HCN + H2O <-> CN- + H+}$

Equation 2: $\ce{NaCN <-> CN- + Na+}$

Equation 3: $\ce{CN- + H2O <-> HCN + OH-}$

I am confused as to:

**1)** the logic behind why we need these three equations (up to this point in the course, all the similar questions have been of the form e.g. *find pH of **NH3** given **Kb(NH3)***, and so we only used the NH3 acid base reaction equation.

I assume equation 1 is necessary because the **Ka** is given for **HCN** and Equation 2 is necessary because we are asked to find the pH of **NaCN**.  Where does Equation 3 come from? We did talk about spectator ions in class so does it have something to do with **Na** being a spectator ion?

**2)** why the ICE (intial, change, at equillibrium) table to find **x** is written in terms of Equation 3 and not, for example, Equation 2.

The solution from the textbook is given below[image: Textbook Solution]:

[image: Textbook Solution]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So strictly speaking you only really need equation 3 to solve this problem, but the first two equations help you figure out how to solve it if you're not too familiar. What do I mean:

> Equation 1: $\ce{HCN + H2O <=> H3O+ + CN-}$

As you correctly note, this is to remind you of the definition for $K_a$

> Equation 2: $\ce{NaCN -> Na+ + CN-}$

Note that I've changed $\ce{<=>}$ to $\ce{->}$. This is because most sodium salts fully dissociate in aqueous solution and so this "equilibrium" doesn't exist and you can then consider all $\ce{NaCN}$ to be converted to $\ce{CN-}$ for your "initial" stage in the ICE table. Hence there's no need to write an ICE Table with respect to Equation 2.

**Value of writing this out:** 
In the case that you were given something sparingly soluble or did not fully dissociate, you would have to consider another equilibrium and this equation 2 would become significant. But in this case, $\ce{Na+}$ is a spectator ion which you can ignore.

> Where does Equation 3 come from?

Equation 3 comes from the question itself (or rather what is happening in the system described). Remember, you've got a 1.0M solution of $\ce{NaCN}$. Since we've already established that it fully dissociates, at the "initial" stage of the system you have only $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{CN-}$ ions floating around. But from Equation 1 you know that $\ce{HCN}$ is a weak acid and so free $\ce{CN-}$ in water may act as a base and take a proton from water, and that is given by the equation:

$$\ce{CN- + H2O <=> HCN + OH-}$$

Comment: Great. Thank you for explaining that IT Tsoi :)

Answer (score 1):

First and Third (sic!) equations are necessary. The second one just says "when I say that 1M solution of NaCN was formed, understand it as 1M of Na+ and 1M of CN- were added to a system".

Your key equilibrium is [HA]=[H+][A-] and [HA]/[H+][A-]=Ka. You then say HA+A- = total_molarity, [HA]=X, [H+]=X, [A-] = total-molarity - X and

x/([x]*[  total-molarity - X] = Ka. You know Ka, total_molarity. You now need to find x. In case of NaCN HCN is HA, CN- is A-.

Just plug your concentrations in the formula and get the result. Quite boring, indeed.